# Connection to your rendering host failed with a Not Found error. Ensure the POST endpoint has been enabled

Tags: jss

I am working with `Sitecore 10.1` and `sitecore-jss 18.0`. I am getting the error - `Connection to your rendering host failed with a Not Found error. Ensure the POST endpoint at URL http://localhost:3000/api/editing/render has been enabled.`

I have already verified the `JSS` editing secret in client and server side configuration. I also went through below solutions:

- https://blog.vitaliitylyk.com/jss-rendering-host/
- https://programmer-swift.medium.com/sitecore-10-1-jss-next-troubleshooting-2b5dec34bbac

But as of now, it's not working. Did anyone face a similar issue?
Any possible solution.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Got the same error with RenderingHost in docker a day ago, still investigating. Front site (RH) works fine, but not preview or EE ,

Comment: The Not Found error can be misleading, could be another HTTP error. Anything in your Sitecore CM logs?

Comment: Did you figure it out @Roman Gupta ? I have the same error,

Answer (score 8):

I experienced the same issue, after some investigation, I found this setting below in

`\App_Config\Sitecore\JavaScriptServices\Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.config`

```
<settings>
  <setting name="JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.JssEditingSecret" value="$(env:SITECORE_JSS_EDITING_SECRET)" />
</settings>
```

So, you can define environment variable, or `override/overwrite` manually like here below:

```
<settings>
  <setting name="JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.JssEditingSecret" value="mysecretkey" />
</settings>
```

This solved my issue.